# C++ prints white blocks instead of Text while writing direct to Videomemory

Tags: c++, operating-system

I'm currently working on my own little os kernel but i'm new to osdev as well as c++.
So after writing my bootloader I researched how to write a simple print function in C++ and came up with this:

```
void print(int color, const char *string){
    volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8000;
    while( *string != 0 )
    {
        *video++ = *string++;
        *video++ = color;
    }
}

extern "C" void main(){
    print((255,255,255), "Hello World");
    return;
}
```

The Problem is it doesn't print the text insertet it prints white(color given to the print statement) blocks with the lenght of the text inserted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `(255,255,255)` to do but it's equivalent to just `255`

Comment: Okay if fixed it. I just had to use another color system